# warbler config and jruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I just installed jruby-1.4.0 to play around with it.  I'm noticing however that warbler is packaging this by default with my rails deploy.  My production uses jruby-complete-1.3.1 (which I've added to my lib dir to freeze the version) but warbler is adding jruby-core-1.4 when it packages everything up.  That's a bit worrisome for me as I don't want any version issues or conflicts, I just want to freeze my jruby version so that I must explicitly change it when I'm ready to upgrade.  Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

The docs I read say that it will take all jars from from WARBLER_HOME and package them, so I assumed that the jruby-core-1.4 was there, but it's not.  How do I omit this from the deploy, or specifically say, "only give me XX version of jruby"

I found warbler home by running:

```
jruby -S gem which warbler
```

Which gives

```
/opt/local/share/java/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/warbler-0.9.14/lib/
```

But it only has a rack jar in there, no reference to jruby-core-1.4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.. I was wondering how exactly that all worked and jruby got on to me production machine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JRuby is included via the separate gem "jruby-jars". Install the 1.3.1 version:

```
jruby -S gem install -v 1.3.1 jruby-jars
```

And then uninstall the 1.4.0 version:

```
jruby -S gem uninstall -v 1.4.0 jruby-jars
```

If gem prompts for confirmation due to dependencies, go ahead and respond with 'y'.